# How do I convert API supplied date/time string into readable format?

Tags: javascript, datetime, ember.js, time

I'm working with a Python backend API that gives me date/time in a string represented as such:

```
2014-07-21T16:50:34.144Z
```

What is this format, and how might I use javascript in my Ember app to put that string into a human readable format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ember actually includes a library(http://momentjs.com/) for handling dates/times. I created a helper with the following code:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('format-date', function(date) {
  return moment(date).format('LLL');
});
```

Then in my handlebars template I have a call to the helper:

```
{{format-date dateCreated}}
```

The helper tag passes the date attribute to the helper, and the moment function handles the formatting. The 'LLL', per the moment.js docs specifies the actual format the date takes. In my case

```
2014-07-21T16:50:34.144Z
```

formats into

```
July 21 2014 9:50 AM
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, simply:

```
var string_date = '2014-07-21T16:50:34.144Z'
var date = new Date(string_date);

date.getDate() // returns 21 -> day
date.getMonth() // returns 6, note it's start counting from 0, so 0 is January.
```

for more info:
[Date object reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: I'd like to add a little info on the type of date that was presented.  This is an ISO-formatted date.  See here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toisostring.asp